# How can I add schema prefix to entity class name when scaffolding with T4 template?

Tags: entity-framework-core, scaffolding

I'm using EF Core power tools to generated `dbcontext`, but when I'm trying to modify T4 template from

```
public partial class <#= EntityType.Name #>
```

to

```
public partial class <#= EntityType.GetSchema() #><#= EntityType.Name #>
```

I get an error

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationException: Processing 'whatever.t4' failed.

I tried to use dotnet cli but it returns the same error.

Did I miss something? or I need to add some kind of assembly references?

Comment: Maybe you need to add a null check?

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(EntityType.GetSchema()))
    {

Answer (score 0):

*Apparently* you cannot render a Null-Value in T4, AND `GetSchema()` returns `null` if the schema is the default schema. I just came across the same error, and these are my conclusions from its occurrence.

I ended up adding a default value if `GetSchema()` is null:

```
<#= entityType.GetSchema() ?? entityType.GetDefaultSchema() #>
```